# How to create customer Profile with multiple payment profiles(CIM)?

Tags: xml-parsing, payment-gateway, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

How to create customer Profile with multiple payment profiles(CIM)?

Creating customer profile with single payment profile is working fine. But when i try to add two or more payment profile to a customer profile , i am getting the below error.

> E00003 - The element 'paymentProfiles' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has invalid child element 'customerType' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'driversLicense, taxId' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.

```
for (int 1=0;i< n;i++){
    list.add (createPaymentProfile());
}

Transaction.setPaymentProfileList(list);
```

The above code generates xml like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<createCustomerProfileRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
   <merchantAuthentication>
      <name>33k7hYV736488Bs8</name>
      <transactionKey>86SV776773Ac6tMV22313fE</transactionKey>
   </merchantAuthentication>
   <refId>1361101257555</refId>
   <profile>
      <merchantCustomerId>2CLINC056</merchantCustomerId>
      <description>hiiiiii.</description>
      <email />
      <paymentProfiles>
         <customerType>individual</customerType>
         <billTo>
            <firstName>Joe</firstName>
            <lastName>Test</lastName>
            <company>CompanyA</company>
            <address>hello</address>
            <city>Bangalore</city>
            <state>Delhi</state>
            <zip>560078</zip>
            <country>IN</country>
            <phoneNumber>415-555-1212</phoneNumber>
            <faxNumber>415-555-1313</faxNumber>
         </billTo>
         <payment>
            <creditCard>
               <cardNumber>370000000000002</cardNumber>
               <expirationDate>2029-12</expirationDate>
            </creditCard>
         </payment>
         <customerType>individual</customerType>
         <billTo>
            <firstName>Joe</firstName>
            <lastName>Test</lastName>
            <company>CompanyA</company>
            <address>vel</address>
            <city>Chennai</city>
            <state>AK</state>
            <zip>560089</zip>
            <country>US</country>
            <phoneNumber>415-555-1212</phoneNumber>
            <faxNumber>415-555-1313</faxNumber>
         </billTo>
         <payment>
            <creditCard>
               <cardNumber>38000000000006</cardNumber>
               <expirationDate>2029-12</expirationDate>
            </creditCard>
         </payment>
      </paymentProfiles>
   </profile>
   <validationMode>testMode</validationMode>
    </createCustomerProfileRequest>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is curious, you must repeat `<paymentProfiles></paymentProfiles>` for each payment profile you wish to create.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<createCustomerProfileRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
   <merchantAuthentication>
      <name>33k7hYV736488Bs8</name>
      <transactionKey>86SV776773Ac6tMV22313fE</transactionKey>
   </merchantAuthentication>
   <refId>1361101257555</refId>
   <profile>
      <merchantCustomerId>2CLINC056</merchantCustomerId>
      <description>hiiiiii.</description>
      <email />
      <paymentProfiles>
         <customerType>individual</customerType>
         <billTo>
            <firstName>Joe</firstName>
            <lastName>Test</lastName>
            <company>CompanyA</company>
            <address>hello</address>
            <city>Bangalore</city>
            <state>Delhi</state>
            <zip>560078</zip>
            <country>IN</country>
            <phoneNumber>415-555-1212</phoneNumber>
            <faxNumber>415-555-1313</faxNumber>
         </billTo>
         <payment>
            <creditCard>
               <cardNumber>370000000000002</cardNumber>
               <expirationDate>2029-12</expirationDate>
            </creditCard>
         </payment>
        </paymentProfiles>
        <paymentProfiles>
         <customerType>individual</customerType>
         <billTo>
            <firstName>Joe</firstName>
            <lastName>Test</lastName>
            <company>CompanyA</company>
            <address>vel</address>
            <city>Chennai</city>
            <state>AK</state>
            <zip>560089</zip>
            <country>US</country>
            <phoneNumber>415-555-1212</phoneNumber>
            <faxNumber>415-555-1313</faxNumber>
         </billTo>
         <payment>
            <creditCard>
               <cardNumber>38000000000006</cardNumber>
               <expirationDate>2029-12</expirationDate>
            </creditCard>
         </payment>
      </paymentProfiles>
   </profile>
   <validationMode>testMode</validationMode>
    </createCustomerProfileRequest>
```